# Recursively calling the same function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was asked to create a function to achieve the following, add up some number and then call the value of them all, ie a chained function of sorts, I created a bad solution, but cannot think of a better way of doing this.

```
add(5).add(10).add(20).value();
```

The interview question just started with an empty function

```
function add() {

}
```

My solution is below, does anybody have any other suggests as I am interested, I've looked at currying, binding etc but not come up with an elegant solution.

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice

function add() {
  var arr = slice.call(arguments);
  return {
    add: function() {
      arr = arr.concat(slice.call(arguments))   
      return this;
    },
    value: function() {
      return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
          return prev + curr;
      });
    }
  }
};
```

**Edit**
Just to clarify I was wondering if there is a way to do this without returning an add function but to call the existing add function.  I think the way that it has been done below is nice, but I think the interviewer was looking for something non-simple.

Comment: I don't find the requirements particularly clear.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. I don't see the recursion just chaining.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirements of what you need to achieve here? At the moment, a recursive function doesn't seem best suited to your purpose.

Comment: Never mind, I understand the requirements now; my bad.

Comment: I don't like it's mutable. For example `a = add(5).add(6); b=a.add(7)` and we have `a.value()==b.value()`

Comment: If, for example, your initial value was 2 would your expected output be 37?

Answer (score 6):

Why so complicated? Don't carry that array of values around with you. Also, try to stay functional and don't mutate it.

```
function add(x) {
    return {
        value: function() {
            return x;
        },
        add: function(y) {
            return add(x+y);
        }
    };
}
```

The key insight here seems to be that chaining doesn't just mean to `return this`, but rather any object of the same class. Immutability dictates that it should be a different object when it has a different sum attached to it.

Comment: Thats a nice solution, pity I did not think of it

Comment: @itzmukeshy7: Should be pretty self-explanatory, and works with the examples given in the OP. What parts don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

seems overcomplicated tbh, here's my answer but maybe I'm not understanding part of the requirements

```
function add(x) {
  return {
    val: 0,
    add: function(x) {
      this.val += x;
      return this;
    },
    value: function() {
      return this.val;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Your first call (to the `add` function, not to the method) doesn't seem to take an argument. And why use `arguments[0]` instead of just declaring a parameter?

Comment: yeh it's using the format from the original answer, I'll update it to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

I like with your idea of lazy calculation, that's why we should keep the chain of operations. But implementation using array has drawback of mutability (see my comment)

I have just written somewhat close to how I see the solution

```
var Calculator = function(initialValue){

    function createOperator(operation) {

        return function(value) {
            return createInstance(operation.bind(null, value));
        }
    }

    function createInstance(reduce) {

         return Object.freeze({

                'add':     createOperator((val) => reduce() + val),

                'subtract':  createOperator((val) => reduce() - val),

                'multiply': createOperator((val) => reduce() * val),

                'divide':   createOperator((val) => reduce() / val),

                'value': reduce

            });
     }

    return createInstance(()=>initialValue);
}

Calculator(0).add(5).multiply(4).subtract(12).divide(2).value(); //returns 4
```

In your problem lazy calculation in not really required, but if we want to preserve chain of operations for multiple use, here it goes. See this example

```
var Calculation = function(){

    function createOperator(operation) {

        return function(value) {
            return createInstance(operation.bind(null, value));
        }
    }

    function createInstance(apply) {

         return Object.freeze({

                'add':      createOperator((val, initial) => apply(initial) + val),

                'subtract': createOperator((val, initial) => apply(initial) - val),

                'multiply': createOperator((val, initial) => apply(initial) * val),

                'divide':   createOperator((val, initial) => apply(initial) / val),

                'apply':    apply

            });
     }

    return createInstance((initialValue)=>initialValue);

}();

var calc = Calculation.add(5).multiply(2).subtract(11);

calc.apply(2); //returns 3

calc.apply(10); //returns 19
```